# Fstream и русский текст. Разница между собственным текстовым файлом и созданным c помощью класса ofstream

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой: программа, открывая заранее созданный мною .txt документ, выводила содержимое в строки, но вместо русских букв появились непонятные символы. Такие функции, как `setlocale`, `SetConsoleCP` и `CharToOem` не помогали.
Спустя несколько часов, я создал ровно такой же .txt документ через `ofstream` и чудом весь текст стал правильно отображаться. С чем может быть связано подобное поведение программы? Как можно было избежать лишних действий с кодом (создание файла непосредственно в самой программе)?

Comment: Разные кодировки. Типа, создали в UTF-8, читаете обычным ifstream, а в UTF-8 русские символы - двухбайтовые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, как и сказал Harry, дело в кодировке. При создании .txt документа кодировка по умолчанию стоит UTF-8, а ofstream создал документ с кодировкой ANSI.